# @Html.Action throws InvalidOperationException for ChildOnlyAction in controller using RouteAttributes

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

It is my understanding that child actions execute using the same routes as the parent actions but I am having difficulty getting this to work. I have an MVC5 application that incorporates several areas. In one area I want to display a partial with some data in every view that is separate from the controller model so I added a child action to accomplish this, but when I try to view any of the pages in that area I get an InvalidOperationException telling me that

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values

The area controller looks like this (simplified for brevity):

```
[RouteArea("SomeArea")]
[RoutePrefix("Here")]
public class PageController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public PageController(IRepository Repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }


    [Route("Page")]
    public ActionResult ShowPage(int pageNumber = 1)
    {
        var model = new PageViewModel(repository, pageNumber);

        ViewBag.Title = "This is a Page";

        return View("ShowPage", model);
    }


    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult DataView()
    {
        var model = new DataViewModel(repository);
        return PartialView("DataView", model);
    }
}
```

The layout for the area:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/pages")
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <br />
        @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Page/Views/Shared/Search.cshtml")
        @RenderBody()

        @Html.Action("DataView", "Page")
    </div>
</body>
```

The route config:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute("Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
```

I have tried catching unhandled routing exceptions as in [this article by David Boike](http://www.make-awesome.com/2012/07/perfectionist-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/) to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated at this point. Thanks

Comment: Can you try to see if by decorating `[Route("DataView")]` on child action that it fixes the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

Answer, supplied by Kiran in the comment above, is to simply decorate the child action with the route value for that action. Thank you Kiran!

I spent an ungodly amount of time researching this, and getting frustrated while I was at it, for such a simple solution. The routing now works with the child action as below:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    [Route("DataView")]
    public PartialViewResult DataView()
    {
        var model = new DataViewModel(repository);
        return PartialView("DataView", model);
    }
```